# How to modify unary operators in OCaml?

Tags: operators, ocaml

In OCaml, it is very easy to access to a binary operator, such as "+":

```
# (+);;

( + ) : int -> int -> int
```

And modify them as I wish:

```
# let (+) = (+.);;

( + ) : float -> float -> float
```

In the Pervasives documentation, it says that `(~-)` is the unary operator corresponding to `(-)`, meaning that `~-5` returns `- :int = -5`.

It is easy to modify `(~-)` as well:

```
let (~-) = (~-.);;

(~-) : float -> float
```

Fortunately, OCaml allows the user to use `(-)` as an alias for `(~-)`:

Suppose we have defined

```
foo : int -> int -> int
```

We can call

```
foo 1 (-1);;
```

which is way better than

```
foo 1 (~-1);;
```

Well, the problem is, when I change `(~-)` definition, it doesn't affect the unary operator `(-)`...

```
let (~-) x = 5;;

~-2;;
- : int = 5

-2;;
- : int = -2
```

Any idea how to modify the unary `(-)` as well ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said, unary `(-)` is a shortcut for `(~-)`. Actually, your change has affected unary `(-)`; for example, you have many ways to use `(-)` as you want after overriding `(~-)`:

```
# - (2+0);;
- : int = 0

# let a = 2;;
val a : int = 2
# -a;;
- : int = 0
```

So it works when you pass an expression to `(-)`. In case you call `-2`, it will be parsed as a value, not a function application. It makes sense to follow the normal convention of negative numbers.

BTW, I don't recommend you to use this way of overriding operators. Since you have change `(-)` for any datatype having that operator, it may lead to confusion and strange bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I totally missed the expression/function call thing!
I'm well aware of the ugliness of what I was proposing, but I'm working on some operator overload/reflection in OCaml, just for fun, so it's meant to be ugly :)

Thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code extract from the compiler that seems to handle this case.  Note that it only works for floating point constants.  It's not a general feature of the `-` operator.

```
signed_constant:
    constant                                    { $1 }
  | MINUS INT                                   { Const_int(- $2) }
  | MINUS FLOAT                                 { Const_float("-" ^ $2) }
  | MINUS INT32                                 { Const_int32(Int32.neg $2) }
  | MINUS INT64                                 { Const_int64(Int64.neg $2) }
```

(You'll find this code in parser.mly.)

I don't think there's a way to get what you want without hacking on the compiler at this spot.